# EXT4 filesystem corruption

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, ext3

I have a CentOS 6x server and running a Java application on it, the application is using a mount point /javapp which is an EXT4 filesystem.

suddenly  I got the following error in the system logs:

> kernel: attempt to access beyond end of device
>    kernel: dm-2: rw=0, want=34359697536, limit=112984064

I found this error may result from one of two possible scenarios:

1. storage resize (LVM or SAN for example)
2. corrupter filesystem

All the pointers suggests a filesystem corruption since I didn't change the size of any backing disks.

My question is, does an application able to corrupt a filesystem?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's your asking, but if your question is if your application is the cause of the file-system corruption, then the answer is usually no. A write operation will trigger the error, but most frequently the actual cause is faulty hardware and/or memory errors.

Comment: @HBruijn, this is exactly my question -- so, a user space application is incapable of corrupting a filesystem, correct?

Answer (score 1):

It is generally not possible for an application to corrupt a filesystem: normal applications do not directly interact with disks, rather they use kernel-level syscalls for reading and writing.

Obviously, applications *designed* to interact with block devices (ie: `fdisk`) **can** corrupt filesystems, but this does not seems your case.

Can you provide the output of the following commands:

- `lsblk`
- `fdisk -l -u <your_device>`
- `pvs`
- `vgs`
- `lvs`
- `df -h`